# for i in ls - Unix syntax

Tags: regex, unix

What is wrong with this?

```
for i in 'ls | grep '^[A-Z]......$'
do
echo $i
done
```

If I just use the command `ls | grep '^[A-Z]......$` I get the files I want

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean

```
for i in `ls | grep '^[A-Z]......$'`;do echo $i;done
```

?
actully this is difference between ` and ' , limited within your shell, and not a regex or OS problem.

Comment: +1 instead of backticks you can also use `$(....)` for command substitution.    
See http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

Answer (score 4):

the thing that is "wrong" , is that there is no need to use external `ls` command to list your files and grep your pattern. Just use the shell.

```
for file in [A-Z]??????
do
 echo $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the backtick: "`" instead of the single quote "'" the output of the program between the backticks will be used as input for the shell, i.e.

```
for i in `ls | grep '^[A-Z]......$'`;do echo $i;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't those be backticks?

```
 for i in `ls | grep blahblahblah`; do echo $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is unnecessary as the shell already do filename expansion:

```
for file in $(ls [A-Z]??????)
do
  echo $file
done
```

Note that filenames with embedded spaces and similar would break this loop.

`ls` can be avoided too fixing the former issue, but a test need then to be added to prevent processing a non existing file when no file match the pattern:

```
for file in [A-Z]??????
do
 [[ -f "$file" ]] && echo $file
done
```